# how to prevent exposure of Notes views from browser

Tags: lotus-domino

How can I prevent that the default views are exposed in my Domino application? is there a special $$form for that?

It seems my application now and looses it web launch property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide all views from web. If it's an XPages application, all views are accessed server-side so never need to be accessible from browser.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I think your suggestion is the best one although I would like to expose the overview of views that are accessible for web browsers in a more elegant, single way

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form called $$ViewTemplateDefault and leave it empty. All views opened from web (with for example the command ?OpenView) will then just display an empty page.

Comment: I have this one but the overview of views accessible for web browsers is still exposed

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do that.  One is with ACL entries.  The other (which you refer to) is to create a form called `$$View Template for [View name]` For example, if your view is called `All documents`, the form would be called `$$View Template for All Documents`.  Just leave the form blank, or put some static text on it ("Access Denied" perhaps.) You should also have one called `$$ViewTemplateDefault` which will cover any views you haven't explicitly protected.